# Using afform components via WordPress shortcodes on non-Pages/Posts

Tags: wordpress, searchkit, formbuilder

I'm trying to use a shortcode to display a Search Kit Form on the Thank You page for a Petition that contains the Date, First Name, and Comment of all the petition signers.

When I input the shortcode, I get an error message: "This Shortcode could not be handled. It could be malformed or used incorrectly."

It works fine on pages/posts, but not on the Petition Thank You Page.